# Don't have access to email address used to make Twitter account; forgot password to Twitter; used real name

Tags: twitter, account-recovery

Five years ago I worked for a startup company where I had to make a Twitter account. I made the account using my work email (which I no longer have access to) and I used my real name. I have now forgotten the password to the Twitter account but would like it back since it does have my real name. I also have since changed phone numbers so I can't receive text messages.

I was thinking I could an email to Twitter and send them a piece of ID proving my name, but I'm not sure which email address to send it to.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Does that company still exist? Did you leave all your passwords with them when you left? If not, maybe they are still automatically logged in and they can do something that way. Contact them, it is not in their interest either that they have an account with your name on it.

Comment: @JanDoggen I ended up contacting the company and eventually got it back. It was a pain though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the reset password via SMS?

### https://twitter.com/account/begin_password_reset

If you did not set up your SMS then check this [Twitter support article](https://support.twitter.com/articles/107907-i-don-t-have-access-to-my-account-s-email-address-anymore).

Comment: Doesn't work because I don't have access to the e-mail address that was used during registration.

Comment: Have you tried the second link? Based on twitter the only way is to contact the email provider and try to regain access to the email account.

Comment: It says "Unfortunately, if you don't have access to the account's email address or verified mobile number, we are unable to continue troubleshooting. While we understand that it can be disappointing when you lose access to an account, we use these verification requirements to make sure we don't give out any user information to the wrong person."